# Update Sub documents in mongodb with where condition

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query, aggregation-framework

I have this collection:

```
{
"_id": 1,
"text": "Breaking News"
"comments" : [
        {
            "comment_id" : "11", 
            "cust_id" : "1", 
            "comments" : "New comments added", 
            "date" : ISODate("2017-10-10T17:36:26.000+0000")
        }, 
        {
            "comment_id" : "12", 
            "cust_id" : "1", 
            "comments" : "second comments added",
            "date" : ISODate("2017-10-11T17:40:54.000+0000")
        }
    ]
}
```

I want is to update `"comments" : "second comments added"` from comments sub-documents where `"comment_id" : "12"`

```
{
    "_id": 1,
    "text": "Breaking News"
    "comments" : [
            {
                "comment_id" : "11", 
                "cust_id" : "1", 
                "comments" : "New comments added", 
                "date" : ISODate("2017-10-10T17:36:26.000+0000")
            }, 
            {
                "comment_id" : "12", 
                "cust_id" : "1", 
                "comments" : "second comments updated by ABC",
                "date" : ISODate("2017-10-11T17:40:54.000+0000")
            }
        ]
    }
```

I have used below query to update it, But it update first comments every times.

```
db.demo.update( {"_id" : '1','comments.comment_id' : '12','comments.cust_id': '1'},
{'$set' : {"comments.$.comments" : "second comments updated by ABC"}})
```

When I use above query it update first comments whose `"comment_id" : "11"` every times.
If I use below query it works fine,

```
db.demo.update( {"_id" : '1','comments.comment_id' : '12'},
    {'$set' : {"comments.$.comments" : "second comments updated by ABC"}})
```

But I need `cust_id` also in where condition.

Please correct me if am doing anything wrong.

Comment: Try `$elemMatch`. Something like `db.demo.update( {"_id" : '1','comments':{$elemMatch:{'comment_id' : '12','cust_id': '1'}},{'$set' : {"comments.$.comments" : "second comments updated by ABC"}})`

Comment: $elemMatch works for me. Thanks @Veeram